# str.translate() method gives error against Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of 3 columns. 2 of the columns I wish to manipulate with are `Dog_Summary` and `Dog_Description`. These columns are strings and I wish to remove any punctuation they may have.

I have tried the following:

```
df[['Dog_Summary', 'Dog_Description']] = df[['Dog_Summary', 'Dog_Description']].apply(lambda x: x.str.translate(None, string.punctuation))
```

For the above I get an error saying:

```
ValueError: ('deletechars is not a valid argument for str.translate in python 3. You should simply specify character deletions in the table argument', 'occurred at index Summary')
```

The second way I tried was:

```
df[['Dog_Summary', 'Dog_Description']] = df[['Dog_Summary', 'Dog_Description']].apply(lambda x: x.replace(string.punctuation, ' '))
```

However, it still does not work!

Can anyone give me suggestions or advice

Thanks! :)

Comment: Please provide an example dataframe. Also your first error message is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wish to remove any punctuation it may have.

You can use a regular expression and `string.punctuation` for this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> s = pd.Series(['abcd$*%&efg', '  xyz@)$(@rst'])
>>> s.str.replace(rf'[{punctuation}]', '')
0     abcdefg
1      xyzrst
dtype: object
```

The first argument to `.str.replace()` can be a regular expression.  In this case, you can use f-strings and a [character class](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/regex.html#matching-characters) to catch any of the punctuation characters:

```
>>> rf'[{punctuation}]'
'[!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~]'  # ' and \ are escaped
```

If you want to apply this to a DataFrame, just follow what you're doing now:

```
df.loc[:, cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda s: s.str.replace(rf'[{punctuation}]', ''))
```

Alternatively, you could use `s.replace(rf'[{punctuation}]', '', regex=True)` (no `.str` accessor).

Comment: Or `df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda s: s.str.replace(rf'[{punctuation}]', ''))` ?